# implicit.empty_implicit_contract error is thrown while creating originated account

Tags: node, tezos-client, account, tezos-admin-client

I have 2 sandboxed tezos nodes running with alpha protocol. 
I'm using eztz to generate new keys.
Once new keys are generated, I'm able to create a transfer operation from bootstrapped account to this new account and also able to bake the operation.

But when I query for the balance on the newly created account, it still shows 0 balance.

If I try to create originated account from this newly created account, it throws 'empty_implicit_contract' error for the new pkh.

What's it it that I'm missing here?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide more details about what you are doing, what you observe, what you expected. Feel free to paste your exact code and/or shell commands into the question, if you are comfortable doing so. (Hopefully OK for sandbox env.)

Comment: I'm getting the same on a sandbox. I used the [alphanet faucet](https://faucet.tzalpha.net/). Balance is always 0